# What application framework I should use?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Folks,
It's a nice scope for me to architect a fairly big portal application. I am aiming to write this application to stay in business for next 5 years at least.
For this application I am considering

1. SilverLight
2. ASP.net MVC
3. Complete (and/or Mixing with ASP.net) JAVA script base framework (jQuery, ExtJS etc).

I know the technical pros and cons of all these technologies more or less. But I really wanted to hear some different opinions/suggestions from other experts.

For example, in the upcoming 5 years I want the product stay onto the top technical insight and flexible too.

Guys any comments, recommendations, suggestions please ?

Comment: You know what you won, and how to do it.. go ahead and do it, what you asking for ? for different road/solutions ? they work also.

Comment: Well, I am asking for some suggestion that will make me more confident to make and execute a decision. that's all.

Comment: This is no correct answer to this question therefore you should make is a community wiki.

Comment: @MSDN Geek, an important thing: is it an intranet application? Do you have control on what's installed on the users machines? If not, you could be in trouble if you choose Silverlight

Comment: @MSDN well I tell you that probably I go with the same tools (except because I do not know MVC I go with winforms). If you know them well continue. I think that ExtJS is too much for web page, is better for web application. jQuery is power :) Silverlight is very new, but adobe flash is something that I hate to programming :) totally different way of programming thinking. So all is cool.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was really looking for this kind of discussion. thanks for your time.

Comment: It's an intranet application by the way. so we have controls over what are installed on work stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net MVC is a safer bet. Should the need arrive, you can migrate to a similar framework with a lot less pain.

You can always use silverlight in v. specific places of the user experience if you need anything advanced. Note you could even use flash for v. specific things instead of silverlight if that fits the bill. Not saying one if better than the other (or that you should use flash over silverlight), just that if you keep them to specific pieces of the app you are not so tied to them.

As for jquery, if you are going to add any javascript to the site Do use it. Its just that good. I prefer/tend to use a progressive js approach, but nowadays it isn't much of an issue.